# Are there many or any Apollo era aerospace types watching this site?

Tags: discussion

I am curious as to how many apollo era (approx 1960s) engineers, scientists, workers, etc are watching this site. I am one and thoroughly enjoy trying to keep up with new technology and contribute any old technology.  If any Apollo vets are tuning in, give a response.  Might be best to send a personal email to me rather than create a long thread but I have a feeling that there will not be many respondees.

Also, I would be curious if anyone knows a site where old Apollo people might congregate. Perhaps one could find an associate there.  I don't do any social media stuff so I am unavailable for that.

If some moderator feels that this should be removed as irrelevant to the site mission, I will understand.

tom kosvic

Comment: An engineer who was 25 in 1960 is 87 in 2022. Hopefully you will find here many of them still alive and at good health.

Comment: There used to be reunions of Apollo folks here in Houston at JSC. I've been out of the biz for almost 10 years now, so I don't know if they still happen. George Abbey is still around, I just talked to him on Tuesday.  The two Apollo people that I worked with and learned a lot from are both dead now though.

Comment: The Outpost Tavern (**the** astronaut bar in the Houston area), aka Building Zero, closed over a decade ago. Yuri's Night (April 12) is not the same now that the Outpost is gone. The new Building Zero just doesn't cut it. Even though my flatulence is very well aged (in other words, I'm an old fart), I'm not old enough to have worked on Apollo.

Comment: Re *I don't do any social media stuff so I am unavailable for that.* You're not alone. Elderly people tend not to use social media, except maybe to use Facebook to communicate with relatives. Many of the people who worked on Apollo retired well before social media was invented. Gene Kranz is still alive, but Glynn Lunney died last year. Only four of the twelve Apollo astronauts who landed on the Moon are still alive. The people who worked on the Space Shuttle are now becoming a dying breed, let alone the people who worked on Apollo.

Answer (score 5):

Both of these dates have passed, but there are key ceremonies every January 28 and April 12. The first date (January 28) is is a solemn occasion. This date is used to mark the Apollo 1, Challenger, and Columbia disasters. Be careful not to be viewed as a stalker if, for example, you take the tour of a NASA space center and look for elderly people.

The second date (April 12) is a celebratory occasion as this date marks both the first flight of a human into space by Yuri Gagarin and the first flight of the US Space Shuttle. This year (2022) many sites renamed the date from "Yuri's Night" to "A Celebration of Space" thanks to Russia's "special military operation" in Ukraine. It's still Yuri's Night to me.

Should you attend one of those ceremonies next year, you might well come across elderly people who worked with the Apollo program. Be polite.

Answer (score 4):

Answer to

> Also, I would be curious if anyone knows a site where old Apollo
> people might congregate. Perhaps one could find an associate there. I
> don't do any social media stuff so I am unavailable for that.

Today I got an email from Frank Hughes, a former head of the Spaceflight Training Division at JSC. He lamented the lack of representation from the training community in the reunions that have been held. And, importantly for your question, he included a website where you can sign up to be notified of reunions, etc. I notice there is an upcoming Apollo reunion.

The website is https://www.mannedspaceops.org/

Answer (score 2):

I heard that many people from NASA go on the app Clubhouse. There are probably a few people from the Apollo era also on the app. Even Jim Green is there.